Why does PHP output \n instead of actually making a newline?
Why does PHP output \n here instead of actually making a newline? I'm viewing it in the terminal and saving into a text file.
It displays wrongly:
Lopende tekst...\nVolgende zin.

It should result in:
Lopende tekst...
Volgende zin.

Code:
<?php
$txt="Lopende tekst... Volgende zin.";
$txt=preg_replace('/(\.{3})( )([A-Z])/','\\1\n\\3',$txt);
echo($txt);
?>


Remember that . is a wildcard in regular expressions. You need to escape it to match the character literally: (\.{3}). And escape sequences aren't processed in strings delimited with single quotes, so \n is literal in your replacement, not a newline.

What do I have to use as a line break instead of \n that actually works? It's not embedded into HTML.

I'm viewing it in the terminal and saving into a text file.

For basic strings the single quotes '' do not have special characters like the \n transformed, use double quotes "" if you want that. The regular expression is exception as it have additional processing where that is taken into account. But the replacement string have only capturing groups.
<?php
$txt="Lopende tekst... Volgende zin.";
$txt=preg_replace('/(\.{3})( )([A-Z])/',"\\1\n\\3",$txt);
echo($txt);
?>

